# getting output from a function in c++

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have written the following code using armadillo in c++. However, I cannot get any output (my outputs are cordX and cordY). Is there something wrong with my definition that it cannot give any output?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

void myOrder(const mat &sOut, const mat &T, const mat &OL, mat &cordX, mat &cordY);

int main()
{
    mat sOut;
    sOut << 100 << 120 << endr;

    mat T;
    T << 20 << 20 << endr;

    mat OL;
    OL << 5 << 5 << endr;

    mat locX;
    mat locY;

    myOrder(sOut, T, OL, locX, locY);

    cout << locX << endl;
    cout << locY << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void myOrder(const mat &sOut, const mat &T, const mat &OL, mat &cordX, mat &cordY)
{
    vector<double> U;
    for (int i = 0; i < sOut(0) - T(0); i += T(0) - OL(0))
    {
        U.push_back(double(i));
    }


    vector<double> V;
    for (int j = 0; j < sOut(1) - T(1); j += T(1) - OL(1))
    {
        V.push_back(double(j));
    }


    if ((double(U.back()) + 2*T(0) - OL(0) - 1) > sOut(0) && (double(U.back()) + T(0) !=sOut(0)))
    {
        U.push_back(sOut(0) - T(0) + 1);
    }
    colvec cordX = conv_to< colvec >::from(U);



    if ((double(V.back()) + 2*T(1) - OL(1) - 1) > sOut(1) && (double(V.back()) + T(1) !=sOut(1)))
    {
        V.push_back(sOut(1) - T(1) + 1);
    }
    colvec cordY = conv_to< colvec >::from(V);

    // return cordX, cordY;
}
```

Comment: You declare local variables with the same name as some of the arguments. Is that on purpose?

Comment: No! Which one(s) do you mean?

Comment: `cordX` and `cordY`. The very two arguments you try to print out after the call.

Comment: I am actually new in c++! Shall I change something? Do I need to rename some?

Answer (score 1):

You declare local variables with the same name as two of the arguments to the function, `cordX` and `cordY`. Declaring them locally *shadows* the arguments, so the arguments will no longer be available to you. Building with more warning enabled should have led the compiler to give you warnings about this.

I assume you meant to assign to the arguments, and not create two new variables.

Comment: I want to return cordX and cordY. So, should not I define them as my input in the function?

Comment: @Sam Pass them by reference like you do now, but don't declare variables with the same name inside the function. I don't know anything about Armadillo, but I guess you should just do e.g. `cordX = conv_to< colvec >::from(U);`, without the initial type that makes `cordX` a new variable.

Comment: You are exactly right. I removed colvec and now it works for the first output, however, the second output (cordY) is all some weird numbers!

Comment: The definition of the second output is the same as the first one, what is wrong with my second output that it give garbage?

Comment: @Sam That is beyond my knowledge, you have to see that you don't put garbage it, or step through the code in a debugger to see what it really puts in.

Answer (score -1):

Myorder function stack will store the result to local variable cordX instead of reference to locX.

1. colvec cordX = conv_to< colvec >::from(U);

so this locX is NULL.

You can do this and respectively to CordY

cordX = conv_to< colvec >::from(U);